# Fetching api and sending the state using Context api

Tags: reactjs

> This is my App.js below and on fetching the data and setState I am
>   unable to display  the date in  child, however my data is fetched in
>   console log. Even i have MyContext in separate file

//App.js

```
class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = { userData: '' }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(userData => {
        this.setState({ userData: userData })
        console.log('here is list =')
        console.log(userData);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={{ state: this.state }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyProvider value={{ state : this.state }}>
          <Header />
          <User />
        </MyProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

//User.js
//Cannot display gender , email in below code

```
class User extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        (context) => (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <p>Gender : {context.state.gender}</p>
                                <p>Email : {context.state.email}</p>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    }
                </MyContext.Consumer>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default User;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Context Provider you are setting the data inside `userData` state and hence you need to access it in consumer like `context.state.userData.gender`. Also since `userData` is an object after the response is available, you should initialise it as an object in Provider constructor as well otherwise you would need to add a check in the `User` component because accessing `email and gender` from userData

```
class MyProvider extends Component {
  state = { userData: {} }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch('https://randomuser.me/api/')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(userData => {
        this.setState({ userData: userData })
        console.log('here is list =')
        console.log(userData);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MyContext.Provider value={{ state: this.state }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </MyContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyProvider value={{ state : this.state }}>
          <Header />
          <User />
        </MyProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**User.js**

```
class User extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MyContext.Consumer>
                    {
                        (context) => (
                            <React.Fragment>
                                <p>Gender : {context.state.userData.gender}</p>
                                <p>Email : {context.state.userData.email}</p>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        )
                    }
                </MyContext.Consumer>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

export default User;
```

Comment: changing to  userData : {} doesnot solve , still unable to display

Comment: are you getting the data from api call. also not only do you need to change `userData: {}` but also how you access it

Comment: Ya I m getting data in cosole   console.log(userData); this is good, and also changed to Gender : {context.state.userData.gender}